# How can I create my Own certificates and key files?

Tags: corda

I have been reading the Corda docs a bit, and recently became interested in create my own certificates and key files. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here for usage examples: https://docs.corda.r3.com/releases/3.3/bridge-configuration-file.html?highlight=keytool. Here it’s used to create keys for bridge-float tunnel.

There’s also an experimental open PR that can help: https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/5101

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/165483) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)